# Timer is Counting Twice as Fast when Called 2nd Time

Tags: excel, vba, timer, countdown

I have a countdown timer I want to repeatedly restart.  However, every time the following TmrPck Sub is subsequently called, it counts the time time down incrementally one second faster.  Note that it correctly stops when I change active sheets but when the sub is again called, it counts down faster.  Either the gCount is building incrementally with each call or the TimeSerial reduction of the xRng.Value is building incrementally.  Which of the two do I need to address to correct and how would I do it?  Sorry for the strange start value of 0.001047 for Range("B9") in my spreadsheet, that just corresponds nicely to 1 minute and 30 seconds for the next timer start.

I've tried to clear the gCount variable when the sheet is deactivated but that failed.

'Following is Code in the sheet, not a standard module:

```
Public Sub TimrPck()
    Dim gCount As Date
    gCount = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime gCount, "ResetTime"
End Sub

Public Sub ResetTime()
    Dim xRng As Range
    Set xRng = Workbooks("TenderAuction.xlsm").Sheets("Pck").Range("B9")
xRng.Value = xRng.Value - TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
If xRng.Value <= 0 Then
    SuperTalk2 "Due to time expiring, ", "Girl", 1, 100
    'Do other work
    Range("B9") = 0.001047
    Exit Sub
End If
If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = "Pck" Then
    Call TimrPck
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Trying to get a clean, standard one-second countdown speed each time this sub is called

Comment: gCount doesn't retain its value between calls - it needs to be a Global variable, and you need to use it to cancel the previous OnTime. or it will continue running.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057696/stopping-the-ontime-event

Comment: Toward the bottom of the stopping-the-ontime-event link, there was some discussion regarding whether the error handler was necessary.  Not sure why, but I was able to cancel the previous OnTime only when the error handler was implemented.  Feels very counter-intuitive to me because I would think the error handler would skip the cancel ask if the error handler was used -- but this did work as I was hoping.  Thanks for the push in the right direction!